# Visual Basic character literals

Tags: vb.net, character

How do I use character literals in VB?
I get error for following code:

```
op as Char
op = '+'
```

> ERROR: Expression expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give a single-character "string" a postfix of `c`:

```
Dim op As Char
op = "+"c
```

Comment: This is not constant. This is variable :)

Comment: @Kamil: I take it that the OP meant "literal", not "constant"; the two are often confused.

Comment: Question is "How do I use character constants in VB?" You can mislead someone.